# Se pierde formato/estilo de títulos de datatable al abrir select múltiple que tengo en td

Tags: javascript, datatables, filtro, dropdownlist, multiselect

Tengo un datatable con filtros tipo select múltiples en td para cada columna (excepto 2 o 3 que no preciso filtrar), el detalle que al abrir alguno de los select para seleccionar algún(as) opciones se pierden los títulos de la tabla, se quitan o se esconden como si perdieran formato o estilo los encabezados del Datatable

**Creando las options del select múltiple**

```
/* Plugin API method to determine is a column is sortable */
$.fn.dataTable.Api.register('column().searchable()', function() {
  var ctx = this.context[0];
  return ctx.aoColumns[this[0]].bSearchable;
});

function createDropdowns(api) {
    api.columns().every(function() {
        if (this.searchable()) {
            var that = this;
            var col = this.index();

        // Only create if not there or blank
        var selected = $('thead tr:eq(1) td:eq(' + col + ') select').val();
        if (selected === undefined || selected === '') {
            // Create the `select` element
            $('thead tr:eq(1) td')
                .eq(col)
                .empty();
      
      $('.selectpicker').selectpicker()
            var select = $(`<select multiple class="form-control form-control-sm selectpicker"><option value=""></option></select>`)
                .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(1) td').eq(col))
                .on('change', function() {
            var selectedValues = $(this).val() || [];
                    that.search(selectedValues.join('|'), true, false).draw();
                    createDropdowns(api);
                });

            api
                .cells(null, col, {
                    search: 'applied'
                })
                .data()
                .sort()
                .unique()
                .each(function(d) {
                    select.append($('<option>' + d + '</option>'));
                });
         }
     }
  });

}
```

**Llamando la Tabla con todas sus propiedades al final se llama la función createDropdowns**

```
async function cargarTablaCreditos(id_credito) {


[if (id_perfil == 3) {
    var id_asesor1 = await consultarIdAsesor();
    console.log("id_asesor1: ", id_asesor1);
  } else {
    var id_asesor1 = 0
  }
  let id_asesor = $('#sCreAsesor').val()
  let status = $('#sCreStatus').val()
  let id_banco = $('#sCreBanco').val()
  let fechas = obtenerFechasDRP($('.drpCreditos'))
  // console.log("fechas_creditos: ", fechas);
  fecha1 = fechas\[0\]
  fecha2 = fechas\[1\]
  let jsonDatos = { "data": \[\] }
  jsonDatos\["data"\].push({
    "id_credito": id_credito,
    "id_perfil": id_perfil,
    "id_usuario": id_usuario,
    "id_asesor": id_asesor,
    "id_asesor1": id_asesor1,
    "status": status,
    "id_banco": id_banco,
    "fecha1": fecha1,
    "fecha2": fecha2
  })

  let jsonCredito = await consultarCreditos(jsonDatos)
  console.log("jsonCredito", jsonCredito)



  let x = 0

  var table = $('#tablaCreditos').DataTable({
    "stateSave": true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": \[
      {
        "extend": 'excelHtml5',
        "exportOptions": {
          "columns": ':visible'
        }
        "extend": 'pageLength',
      },
      'colvis'
    \],
    "language": datatable_lenguaje\[0\],
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": 650,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "fixedColumns": {
      left: 4
    },
    "fixedHeader": true,
        "orderCellsTop": true,
    "order": \[\[69, 'DESC'\], \[2, 'DESC'\], \[1, 'DESC'\]\],
    "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
      if (data\[19\] == "<strong>SUBTOTALES:</strong>") {
        $(row).css({
          'background-color': '#39A44C',
          'color': '#FFF',
          'font-weight': 'bold',
          'font-size': '12px'
        });
      }
      if (x == 0) {
        $('td:eq(0), td:eq(1), td:eq(2), td:eq(3)', row).css({
          'background-color': '#d0f2d6',
          'color': '#000'
        })
        x = 1
      } else {
        $('td:eq(0), td:eq(1), td:eq(2), td:eq(3)', row).css({
          'background-color': '#f2fff5',
          'color': '#000'
        })
        x = 0
      }
    },
    "columnDefs": \[
      {
        "targets": \[9, 69\],
        "visible": false,
      },
      {
        "targets": \[0, 1, 13\],
        "searchable": false
      },
      {
        "targets": \[0, 1, 2\],
        "className": "text-center"
      },
    \],
    "initComplete": function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        createDropdowns(this.api());
      }, 250);
        }
      }).clear().draw()][1]
```

*antes de abrir el select*
[image: antes de abrir el select]

*al abrir el select*
[image: al abrir el select]

Aparte no se alcanza a ver las opciones del select en su totalidad sino que solo muestra una parte la cual si le doy scroll si se muestran pero solo en ese pequeño espacio.

Comment: Parece ser un problema de CSS, pero sin un [MCVE] es imposible ayudarte

Comment: @Yussef prácticamente soy nuevo en ésto de la programación(alrededor de 1 año), me podrías ayudar u orientar como podría agregar un ejemplo como el que mencionas?

Comment: Hola Daniel, tu error proviene de la implementación particular que estas haciendo. Al ser tan particular, es altamente improbable que alguien pueda determinar el problema solo mirando el código que has puesto, por lo que se necesita un [MCVE], el cual es el código mínimo para reproducir el problema. En otras palabras un código que yo pueda copiar/pegar y ver el mismo error que tu tienes sin necesidad de hacer nada mas. Este [MCVE] puede (o no) tomar bastante trabajo construirlo, pero hay casos (como creo que es el tuyo) que no hay otra alternativa